# MS SQL Query Returns False Data To Application

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

My view page is not showing the true values that are in the database.

I have these lines in a model class:

```
public static db_XXXXXXx db = new db_XXXXXX();
```

`public IEnumerable<Booking> Bookings = db.Bookings.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Bookings] WHERE RoomId IS NULL");`

and in my controller is:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var bookings = new List<Booking>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            bookings.Add(new Booking());
        }

        var model = new ClerkBookingViewModel
        {
                Bookings = bookings
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

If i run the same query directly on db from SQL Server Management Studio - 1 row is returned and none of the values are 0 but my webpage is showing unexpectedly as the values aren't 0.

Booking ID 0 Bunks Required 0

Comment: Well, in your controller you're adding 10 "new Booking" to your list. Aren't those the 0s you're seeing?

Comment: But the 10 should represent how many bookings I want to write on the page?

Comment: But when you add 10 empty bookings, you have 10 0's I suspect.

Comment: I want to work out why the bookings are empty?

Comment: Bookings are empty because you've done `new Booking()` ten times and then returned it.

Comment: Unfortunatley I cant see a way around this